# how to impute missing value using R's multinom

Tags: r

Suppose my data frame `DF` has two colums `$A` and `$B`. `$A` is always present. `$B` is sometimes coded NaN when the value is missing. I want to predict `$B.predicted`, the missing values for `$B`, and create a new column `$B.complete` such that `$B.complete[i]` is `$B.predicted` if `$B[i]` is NaN and is `$B[i]` otherwise.

I use multinom, which requires a factors as the dependent variable, to predict the B's where I have a full observation, using:

```
DF$B.factor <- factor(DF$B)
model.results <- multinom(formula=B.factor ~ A,
                          data=DF[!is.na(DF$B),])
B.predicted <- predict(model.result, newdata=DF, type="class")
```

The variable `B.predicted` is a factor.

My `DF$B` column is not a factor.

Mu question is how to I merge `DF$B` and `B.predicted` to create `B.complete`? In particular, since `B.predicted` is a factor and `DF$B` is not, does this code pick up the correct values?

```
B.complete <- ifelse(is.na(DF$B), $B.predicted, DF$B)
```

Comment: What is with all the superfluous  leading `$` signs.

Comment: Give some example data, and make sure that your code runs with it.  That will mean removing these leading `$` signs.

Comment: On a statistical basis this sounds like a Very Bad Idea. You can plot the results with the data you have. There really is no basis for forcing in predictions in the missing locations. (And then you shoot yourself in the foot by passing back in the NA values from the original dataframe.)

Answer (score 1):

Use `replace`

```
set.seed(1)

DF <- data.frame(A = factor(sample(letters[1:5],30, TRUE)), 
 B = sample(c(letters[1:3],NA), 30 , TRUE, prob = rep(c(0.3,0.1),c(3,1))), 
 stringsAsFactors = F)

DF$B.factor <- factor(DF$B)

# no need to include is.na(DF$B) as multinom will omit anyway
model <- multinom(B.factor ~ A, data = DF)

# use replace to replace the NA values (converting to character when necessary)
DF$B.complete <- replace(DF$B, is.na(DF$B),  as.character(predict(model, newdata = DF[is.na(DF$B),])))
```